# How to add two 24hour times

Tags: c

Hi pretty new to coding in c, but would love your help in my following coding problem.

I want to add two times (that are in twenty four hour time notation already).

Currently they are both integers and the arithmatic addition function is great for whole hour (e.g. 800+1000), however because our / computer's numbers are base ten, it will not roll over to the next hour after 60min which leads to problems with addition.

I'm not sure if the modulus % can solve this? Ideally I would like to use simple c coding (that I understand), and not start importing  timing keys into the program.

e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{

int time1 = 1045; // 10:45am in 24hour time
printf("Time %d ",time1);


int time2 = 930; //9 hours & 30min
    printf("+ time %d", time2);    

int calc = time1 + time2;
printf(" should not equal ... %d\n", calc);

printf("\nInstead they should add to %d\n\n", 2015); //8:15pm in 24hr time

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are manipulating timespans, you should look at `struct tm`, defined in `<time.h>`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're correct that modulo division is involved.  Remember, that is **remainder** division.  This is more worthy as a comment since supplying a complete answer for problems like this is generally frowned upon, but it's too long for that; this should get you started:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  // Assuming the given time has the format hhmm or hmm.
  // This program would be much more useful if these were
  // gathered as command line arguments
  int time1 = 1045;
  int time2 = 930;

  // integer division by 100 gives you the hours based on the
  // assumption that the 1's and 10's place will always be
  // the minutes
  int time1Hours = time1 / 100;  // time1Hours == 10
  int time2Hours = time2 / 100;  // time2Hours == 9

  // modulus division by 100 gives the remainder of integer division,
  // which in this case gives us the minutes
  int time1Min = time1 % 100;  // time1Min == 45
  int time2Min = time2 % 100;  // time2Min == 30

  // now, add them up
  int totalHours = time1Hours + time2Hours;  // totalHours = 19
  int totalMin = time1Min + time2Min;  // totalMin = 75

  // The rest is omitted for you to finish
  // If our total minutes exceed 60 (in this case they do), we
  // need to adjust both the total hours and the total minutes
  // Clearly, there is 1 hour and 15 min in 75 min. How can you
  // pull 1 hour and 15 min from 75 min using integer and modulo
  // (remainder) division, given there are 60 min in an hour?

  // this problem could be taken further by adding days, weeks,
  // years (leap years become more complicated), centuries, etc.

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Additionally: leapseconds, daylight saving times (they can change in between), timezones (they can change in between), different calendars, and all of what I have suppressed^Wforgotten, too. tl;dr: don't do dates&time, never! You cannot get payed enough to do it! Use the libraries the language or a third party offers for date&time.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi I totally agree, but I think it's pretty clear from the context of the question this is a variation of the "make change" problem from compsci 101 and isn't intended to be the origin of a useful, robust time library.

Answer (score 1):

I used this for a long time...

```
// convert both times hhmm to minutes an sum minutes
// be sure to do integer division 
int time1m = ((time1 / 100) * 60)+(time1 % 100);
int time2m = ((time2 / 100) * 60)+(time2 % 100);
int sumMin = time1m + time2m; 
// convert back to hhmm
int hhmm = ((sumMin / 60) * 100)+(sumMin % 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also include a day, as time is of 24 hour format.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int t1=2330;
    int t2=2340;
    int sum=((t1/100)*60)+(t1%100)+((t2/100)*60)+(t2%100);
    int day=sum/(24*60);
    sum = sum % (24*60);
    int hours=sum/(60);
    int mins=sum % 60;
    printf("days = %d \t hours = %d \t mins=%d\n",day, hours, mins);
    return 0;
}
```